# NDSolve and UnitStep function

Tags: differential-equations

I am reposting my question because I accidentally deleted the previous one instead of editing. I am trying to solve the system using NDSolve

```
l = 10^-5; ϵ = 1; x0 = -70; tmax = 150; v = 0.9;
roz = NDSolve[{\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(t, t\)]\(ϕ[x, t]\)\) - \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x\)]\((\((1 + ϵ*\((1/2)\)*\((UnitStep[x] - UnitStep[x - l])\))\)*\((\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x\)]ϕ[x, t])\))\)\) + Sin[ϕ[x, t]] == 0, ϕ[x, 0] == 4 ArcTan[E^((x - x0)/Sqrt[1 - v^2])], \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ϕ\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}], Derivative], MultilineFunction->None]\)[x,0] == -((4 E^((x - x0)/Sqrt[1 - v^2]) v)/((1 + E^((2 (x - x0))/Sqrt[1 - v^2])) √(1 - v^2))), ϕ[-200, t] == 0, ϕ[200, t] == 2*π}, ϕ, {x, -200, 200}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

but I'm running into a trouble

```
NDSolve::ndnum Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`
```

I know that I can approximate `UnitStep` by `Tanh`, but due to the very small values of $l$, in this approach the results I get are incorrect. Is there any way to use `UnitStep` here?

I would very much appreciate some help.

Comment: Your system creates `Indeterminate`s at `x==0` (and another value defined by your parameters) due to your defition of UnitSteps inside of derivatives. Pluggin them to 0 (or any other value really..) solves this. So add `/. Indeterminate -> 0` behind the equation-list definition. But also be aware of the implications you take here. There is a reason Mathematica renders this value Indeterminate.

Comment: What's the purpose of `(UnitStep[x] - UnitStep[x - l]))` ? You try to aprroximate `DiracDelta`?